# php date and strtotime for next year return current year

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have faced a small issue. check the below code

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('15 Nov, 2018'));
```

I was expecting that it will return 2018-11-15 but when i echo the result it returns 2016-11-15,

Can some one tell me what is the issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of comma. Following works fine after removing comma:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace(',','','15 Nov, 2018')));
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing the comma : `echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('15 Nov 2018'));`

Read more about the supported formats here : [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0):

Remove comma after Nov

echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('15 Nov 2018'));

it will give you the correct result